# DataGridView validate fields

Tags: vb.net

Have datagridview which is bound to datasource. There is also possibility to add new row for user. User can modify all rows fields as well as add new row with data. My aim is to validate few things:

```
1. Check whether all fields have been filled out
2. Check whether correct values type's have been typed by user
3. Check whether new row ("if touched") has been filled also correctly.
```

Table fields are:

```
Id (hided)
Name (string)
Lage (string)
Wahrung (string)
Nummer (integer)
Date (date)
```

What i have at the moment is:

Load data from datasource

```
 Private hersteller As Hersteller

    Private Sub FrmProducents_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
         InitGrid()
    'due to not run it during first grid bind from datasource
    AddHandler Grid.RowValidating, AddressOf Grid_CellValidating
    End Sub

    Private Sub InitGrid()
         hersteller = New Hersteller
         Grid.DataSource = hersteller.GetHerstellerDS.Tables(0)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Grid_CellValidating()
         'Suppose every logic to be implemented here
    End Sub
```

Comment: There is simple DV and enforcing business/app logic.  Some of the former can be automatic - users can only enter dates into date cols, for instance. BL logic is usually not located in the UI but a class dedicated to that entiry (Customer, Employee, Product). That `Grid_CellValidating` signature is nto correct, but I guess that is just sample/idea...

Comment: @Plutonix could you put any answer with some sample Plutonix?